# How to trigger correctly in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a trigger from MySQL with these conditions. And I am really a new to use MySQL.

**My Steps:**

1) Update before changes on table A

2) I have 2 fields in these table A: FieldToSum (with 1 or 0 in many rows) and SUM (that have to be updated, querying the sum of FieldToSum data.

3) My code doesn´t work:

```
DELIMITER $$
     CREATE TRIGGER before_sums
     before update ON tableA
   BEGIN
     UPDATE tableA SET SUM=select sum(FieldToSum) from tableA;
   END
$$
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what are you trying to achieve? First of all - your approach is wrong and confusing because you're trying to update table before update... and in the trigger you're using the same table - that will give you an error..
UPD: Also, you have an error in you're update syntax - it should be smth like `UPDATE tableA SET SUM=(SELECT SUM(FieldToSum) FROM tableA);` - but it also wrong :)

Comment: In my tableA i have two fields:fieldtosum and sum. The sum field shoulf be a computed field wich is the sum of all fieltosum rows. Imagine that i have 3,5,8 in fieldtosum. My SUM field should have 16,16,16.

Comment: This is a very bad design. You dont need. when ever  you need this value you can use an sql statement.

Comment: I know but i really need it like a trigger.thank you.